# Is it possible to iterate over a returned function in golang with a for loop?

Tags: go

Say we have this:

```
func foo() func() int {
    return func() {
        for i := range [0..10] {
            return i
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    for i := foo() {

    }
}
```

Can I iterate over the returned function in a for loop without knowing how many times it will loop?

Comment: First of all you are trying to return a function which return a number in a for loop (this should return only once), but which does not have a return type. And above all, the main function return type is a string. So there are a lot of inconsistencies.

Comment: It would really help if you make the non-relevant parts of your question valid Go, rather than making up syntax and asking us to decipher it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For example,

```
package main

import "fmt"

func foo(n int) func() (int, bool) {
    i := -1
    return func() (int, bool) {
        if i >= n {
            return 0, true
        }
        i++
        return i, false
    }
}

func main() {
    f := foo(5)
    for i, eof := f(); !eof; i, eof = f() {
        fmt.Println(i)
    }
}
```

Output:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
```

Comment: I have been missing the "second" call to `f()` define on the third part of the `for` definition. Thanks @peterSO

Answer (score 1):

You can't iterate over a function alone. A function returns only once, so your for loop would never loop. If you wanted to return a closure over `i`, you could increment it each call, but you still need a way to know when to stop, which you could do by returning multiple values from the inner function.

Go also uses channels for communication, which you can `range` over.

```
func foo() chan string {
    ch := make(chan string)
    go func() {
        for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
            ch <- strconv.Itoa(i)
        }
        close(ch)
    }()
    return ch
}

func main() {
    for i := range foo() {
        fmt.Println(i)
    }
}
```

http://play.golang.org/p/oiFTAgyeJd